# How to change position of button in widget (kivy)

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a space invaders game with kivy and I want a fire button for the spaceship to shoot. Everything is working, I can shoot and the render text on the button. But the only thing is I cant change the position of the button. It is not moving . I also tried with a Floaltlayout in a widget. But still only the size is changing but the position is not changing, How could I change it. I think it is not changing because I inherit the class from widget

```
class SpaceGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SpaceGame,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = FloatLayout()
        button = Button(text='Fire',size_hint=(.8,1),pos_hint={'top':.8,'right':.7},on_release=lambda *args: self.serve_ball(*args))
        layout.add_widget(button)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]..

Comment: The problem is likely that you have defined a `pos_hint` for the `Button`. Since `pos_hint` take precedence over `pos`, animating `pos` will have no effect. Try removing the `pos_hint`.

Comment: I added pos but no luck either